# Saving PHP session data to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am having to update my session code to save it to the db, I am using the same code that is here: https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions

I have my session class setup, with the write function like so:

```
     public function _write($id, $data){  
     // Create time stamp  
     $access = time();

     // Set query  
     $this->db->query("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data)");

     // Bind data  
     $this->db->bind(":id", $id);  
     $this->db->bind(":access", $access);  
     $this->db->bind(":data", $data);

     // Attempt Execution  
     // If successful  
     if($this->db->execute()){  
     // Return True  
     return true;  
     }

     // Return False  
    return false;  
 }
```

However no session data gets stored in my db table, setup like this:

```
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | varchar(32)      |      | PRI |         |       |
| access | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| data   | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

As an example, can I simply use:

```
$session = new Session();
_write('1', 'test');
```

To save session data?

My code that needs modifying is like so:

```
$_SESSION['lightbox_list']['attachments'] = $data->attachments;
$_SESSION['lightbox_list']['name'] = $data->name;
$data->last_insert = $queried_post->ID;
die( json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$session->_write('1', 'test');`?

Comment: Atleast read the manual en examples https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions/blob/master/example.php

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes you are right!

Comment: No @RonvanderHeijden and @user43251 function `_write` is a custom session handler call..Check the this class https://github.com/dominicklee/PHP-MySQL-Sessions/blob/master/mysql.sessions.php .. And is **not** meant to be called directly..

Comment: Can I still store something like this: $_SESSION['lightbox_list']['attachments'] = $data->attachments;

Comment: Does the MySQL user that is used in de PHP code have INSERT and DELETE privileges for the table sessions? Because REPLACE requires this.. Atleast use a mysql debugging error message function like mysqli_error or errorInfo to see if the query contains a error.